# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.DataSourceV2 for Spark 3.0.0

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

### Brief

**What are possible paths that can make me process data by pyspark 3.0.0 with success from the pure `pip` installation, well, at least loading data without downgrading the version of Spark?**

When I attempted to load datasets of `parquet` and `csv`, I would get the exception message as the content below *Exception Message* displays. The initialization of Spark session is fine, yet when I wanted to load datasets, it just went wrong.

### Some Information

- Java: openjdk 11
- Python: 3.8.5
- Mode: local mode
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Notes:

  1. I executed `python3.8 -m pip install pyspark` to install Spark.
  2. When I looked up the jar of `spark-sql_2.12-3.0.0.jar` (which is under the Python site-package path, i.e., `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/jars` in my case), there is no `v2` under `spark.sql.sources`, the most similar one I found is an interface called `DatSourceRegister` under the same package.
  3. The most similar question I found on Stackoverflow is [PySpark structured Streaming + Kafka Error (Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.StreamWriteSupport )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362841/pyspark-structured-streaming-kafka-error-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundex) where downgrading the Spark version is recommended throughout the information on that page.

### Exception Message

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o94.csv.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/DataSourceV2
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:255)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:249)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:347)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:347)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:705)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.DataSourceV2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: pyspark is bundled with Spark itself, you may not need to install it separately.  Also, check with `pip list` command that you dont have another version

Comment: @AlexOtt , thanks for reminding. I know Python is just a wrapper since the core of Spark is written by Scala and pyspark actually works by manipulating Java objects via py4j. A point I mentioned in the post for looking up the jar is by checking it under `${SPARK_HOME}/jars` and ${SPARK_HOME} is under the Python site-package path, which is `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark` in my case.

Comment: Did you use the spark 3.0.0 binary without hadoop? I was able to brew install a local spark 3.0.0 on a macbook that is able to read files. If I call `spark_session.read.parquet()` using the spark binary without hadoop on an Ubuntu cluster I ran into the same issue. Although the java class that's not found for me is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/ReadSupport`. So I'm wondering if this is a reproducible issue for the `spark-3.0.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz` binary.

Comment: @bricard only have tried the installation by pip and building from sources. Maybe I could try downloading the binary that you mentioned, checking whether I'll encounter the same or similar issue by running the standalone mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem with spark 3 and finally figured out the cause. I was including a custom jar that relied on the old datasource v2 api.

The solution was to remove the custom jar then spark began working properly.

Comment: I built up a Spark cluster few days ago, with standalone mode which is composed of one master and four workers. I downloaded `spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz` to build up. And I can retrieve data with formats that Spark supports from AWS S3 without the exception message or similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

currently, I have got a way out for manipulating data via Python function APIs for Spark.

## workaround

**1**

```sh
# clone a specific branch 
git clone -b branch-3.0 --single-branch https://github.com/apache/spark.git
## could try the follwoing command
## git clone --branch v3.0.0 https://github.com/apache/spark.git

# build a Spark distribution
cd spark
./dev/make-distribution.sh --name spark3.0.1 --pip --r --tgz -e -PR -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pmesos -Pyarn -Dhadoop.version=3.0.0 -DskipTests -Pkubernetes
## after changing the value of SPARK_HOME in `.bashrc_profile`
source ~/.bashrc_profile

# downlaod needed additional jars into the directory
cd ${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.0.0/hadoop-aws-3.0.0.jar
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.828/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.828.jar
cd ${SPARK_HOME}

# add related configuraionts for Spark
cp ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf
## add required or desired parameters into the `spark-defaults.conf`
## as of me, I edited the configuraion file by `vi`

# launch an interactive shell
pyspark
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Python version 3.8.5 (default, Jul 24 2020 05:43:01)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
## after launching, I can read parquet and csv files without the exception
```

**2**
after setting up all the stuff mentioned above, add `${SPARK_HOME}/python` to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, then remember to source the related file (I added it into `.bashrc_profile`).

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkConf()
threads_max = 512
connection_max = 600
sc.set("spark.driver.memory", "10g")
sc.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.threads.max', threads_max)
sc.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum', connection_max)
sc.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider',
           'com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider')
sc.set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', 0)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("cest-la-vie")\
    .master("local[*]").config(conf=sc).getOrCreate()
## after launching, I can read parquet and csv files without the exception
```

## notes

I've also attempted to make PySpark pip installable from the sources' building, but I was stuck on the uploading file size to `testpypi`. This trying is that I want the pyspark package to be present under the site package directory. The following is my attempting steps:

```sh
cd ${SPARK_HOME}/python
# Step 1
python3.8 -m pip install --user --upgrade setuptools wheel
# Step 2
python3.8 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel ## /opt/spark/python
# Step 3
python3.8 -m pip install --user --upgrade twine
# Step 4
python3.8 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
## have registered an account for testpypi and got a token
Uploading pyspark-3.0.1.dev0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

## stuck here
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 345M/345M [00:49<00:00, 7.33MB/s]
Received "503: first byte timeout" Package upload appears to have failed.  Retry 1 of 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a standalone installation of Spark 3.1.1.

I have tried a lot of things.

I have excluded a lot of jar files.

After a lot of suffering, I decided to delete my Spark installation and install(unpack) a new one.

I don't know why... but it's working.